# Table Not Being Styled For Mobile | CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm experiencing some problems with my two stylesheets.
I've been trying to make my website mobile friendly so I created a separate CSS file for mobile. Like so:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media = "screen" href="css/services.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type= "text/css" href="css/mobile/services.css" 
    media ="only screen and (max-width: 500px)" />
```

Except I've run into a problem with overiding the main CSS file with the mobile one for a specific problem (only one part is not overriding; everything else is fine).

In "css/services.css" (the main one) I have:

```
#pricing{
    margin: 0px;
}
.pricing_tables{
    width: 600px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

And in "css/mobile/services.css" (the mobile version) I have:

```
#pricing{
    width: 270px;
}
.pricing_tables{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 270px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Basically, I can't change it to have a smaller width. But I haven't run into any problems until now.

The element I'm trying to change is a table. #pricing is the  also set at width:270px

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any reason why you wouldn't simplify your life and combine your two stylesheets into one?

See if this helps you: 
http://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/BpNMvz

CSS

```
#pricing{
    margin: 0px;
}
.pricing_tables{
    width: 600px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {

  #pricing{
    width: 270px;
  }
  .pricing_tables{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 270px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }

}
```